# BeautifulSoup - how to select separate values?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In my scrapper I use .select("div.class-name") method but have a trouble: it returns non-separated values.

Structure of my html:

```html
<div class="class-name">
   <div>Text1</div>
   <div>Text2</div>
   <div>Text3</div>
</div>
```

And as a result it gives me a list ["Text1Text2Text3"]. Is there any way to separate it as in html?

Comment: Could you provide snippet of python code which provided you mentioned result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_html = '''<div class="class-name">
   <div>Text1</div>
   <div>Text2</div>
   <div>Text3</div>
</div>'''

print(BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "lxml").select("div.class-name div"))
```

Output:

```
[<div>Text1</div>, <div>Text2</div>, <div>Text3</div>]
```